# How to convert a dictionary pair.value to a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary

i have the following JSON in my application.

```
string json = @"{""dest"":[ { ""mode"": ""1"", ""test"":""test1,test,test2""},{ ""mode"": ""2"", ""test"": ""test3"" }]}";
```

To get the value of **dest** I m using the following method.

```
 var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = json_serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

     public Dictionary<string, object> GetObject(Dictionary<string, object> view, string name)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                object value = null;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in view)
                {
                    Type type = pair.Value.GetType();
                    if (pair.Key == name)
                    {
                        **Dictionary<string, object> child = (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>)pair.Value;**
                        result = GetObject(child, name);
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
```

I m getting error in the line  **Dictionary child = (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary)pair.Value;**. 
The error says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Casting does not change the objects type. See [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) - you'll have to pick the rules for picking the key/value from each element in the sequence.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: First start by identifying what is in the Key and Value or `pair`  and how those values should be converted to keys and values in the new dictionary. Because of the ugly untyped nature you'll have to first cast `pair.Value` into an `ArrayList`. e.g. `child = ((ArrayList)pair.Value).ToDictionary(p => /* selector for key */, p => /* selector for value */)`.

Comment: child = ((ArrayList)pair.Value).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p.value => /* selector for value */); I tried the above but getting error.

Comment: Well, yes. That's invalid syntax (`p.value => /* wrong /*`) and, even if it wasn't invalid syntax it'd a type error because there are not Key or Value members of object. In this case, `p` is typed as object, because that is what ArrayList is typed as - sequence of generic objects. You'll likely need to cast the value (`p`) before using it usefully. Again, *identify what is in .. Value*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tset` in your array is a typo and it actually is `test`, you can use concerete classes ....

```
string json = @"{""dest"":[ { ""mode"": ""1"", ""test"":""test1,test,test2""},{ ""mode"": ""2"", ""test"": ""test3"" }]}";
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(json);

public class Dest
{
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public List<Dest> dest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so If my json is like below how can i get the value of dest?string json = @"{"id":"101",""dest"":[ { ""mode"": ""1"", ""test"":""test1,test,test2""},{ ""mode"": ""2"", ""test"": ""test3"" }]}";

Comment: sorry..I couldnt find any mistake.

Comment: @user1357872 `so If my json is like below`, of course I can give another answer for this json but how many times will we repeat this question/answer session? You have an answer for your question you posted. Does it work or not, given the data in your question?

Comment: I need an answer which is compliant with the sample I provided. Also what you gave is using list and the result will be a string. I need a dictionary object to be returned. I already replied to your answer that its not the answer i wanted.

Comment: @user1357872 `already replied to your answer that its not the answer i wanted` No you just asked another question `so If my json is like below how can i get the value of dest`

Comment: Even if my question is the same, will your answer be correct? what I asked and what you answered??? Please read the question before answering. and also try to provide an answer that will be useful to others.

Comment: @user1357872 I tested my answer before posting (Full code is in my answer). Don't be a jerk and please ask useful questions that would be useful to others.

Comment: I dont want to ask questions that you know. and please dont answer if you dont know.